# Resetting a remote branch without pushing the local branch

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-remote, git-reset

I have the following situation in my project:

[image: screenshot]

I would like to get rid of the merge commit (`c6ac755`) and rebase `master` on `b35dac5` instead. To this end, I would like to reset `origin/master` to `b35dac5`, rebase `master` on `origin/master` and then synchronize with GitHub. How can I reset `origin/master` *without* changing `master` and pushing it to `origin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you merged `origin/master` locally (probably with `git pull`), pushed the merge and then reset the local `master` branch with something like `git reset --hard HEAD~1`.

---

In this state, you can use *push* to set the remote branch to the desired commit:

```sh
git push --force origin b35dac5:master
```

After this, you can rebase `master` on `origin/master`:

```sh
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
```